# HTML tables not opening in Outlook (pd.to_html)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, email, outlook

I am using pd.to_html for sending my pandas dataframe over email, the emails are opening fine in Gmail browser with all the tables in the email body. But they are not opening in Outlook all the tables are going as an HTML attachment in outlook.

Using the following code for converting my dataframe to HTML.

**df_1 = df_1.to_html(index=False,header= True,border=4,justify = 'left',col_space =9)**

**from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(df_1))**

This is how I am sending the Email:-

```
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email import encoders

    email_user = 'xyz@x.com'
    email_password = '*********'
    email_send = 'xyz@x.com'
    subject = 'ABCDEF'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject


    body_1 = """ Hey All,

    Please find the data:

    """
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body_1,'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(df_1,'html'))

    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,email_password)

    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send.split(','),text)
    server.quit()
```

There are no error's email is opening in Gmail properly. But in outlook tables are coming as an attachment.

Comment: We'd need to see how you are sending / creating the email.

Comment: Hey, Rich, I have edited the Q's with additional details pls check and let me know if there is any solution for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a single attachment as html.That worked for me.

```
df_1 = df_1.to_html(index=False,header= True,border=4,justify = 'left',col_space =9)

mailBody= """<p> Hi All, <br><br>

Please find the data: </p> <br><br>
""" + df_1 + """<br> Thanks. """

msg.attach(MIMEText(mailBody,'html'))
```